# Sublime Text "Find and Replace" doesn't work

Tags: search, sublimetext3

Let's say I have this folder in a project: `/xxx/yyy`

If I look for a certain string inside folder `/yyy`, Sublime will show me the results, even if it has found it within a file inside a subfolder of `/xxx/yyy`, let's say, `/xxx/yyy/zzz/whatever.cshtml` (that means it's searching recursively)

BUT, If I look for the same string inside the folder `/xxx` (the parent folder), nothing happens and I get no results.

Why? Does it have a limit for searching recursively? Maybe it can't handle too many files?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I realised now that it works, it's just too fricking slow. But the project is quite huge plus it's accessing files on another computer and Sublime Text for some reason doesn't give proper feedback about the search (e.g. takes +- a minute to show the message "Searching 38415 files for xxxx")

Comment: I'm using the `ctfl+shift+f`, `Find` works immediately for all files, but `Replace` doesn't seem to be doing anything for me, so I'm having to `F4` for now to open each file from the results, then `ctrl+h` to `Replace All` :(